# Magento Products aligning to bottom

Tags: image, magento, product

Im using magento for an online store and have created my own block and script to show new and special priced products.

Its working perfectly but some of the products arent aligning properly.

[image: Mis-aligning products]

They seem to be aligning to the bottom of the container so the images look out of line, what i would like is for the images all to align to the top. Using firebug i cant find the CSS which is making them align to the bottom!

The only CSS i have applied is:

```
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel ul {text-align: center; background:#E5E1D5; }
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel ul li {width:24.7%;}
```

Any ideas from you magento pros?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS :

```
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel ul {text-align: center; background:#E5E1D5; position: relative;}
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel ul li {width:24.7%; position: absolute; top: 0;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i already tried this as i thought of it first thing but instead the products all end up sitting on top of each other. Cheers